# Trying to have eventHandler in its own class access to another class's method

Tags: javascript, class, oop, dom

I am trying to understand how to use Classes to divide my functions by its purpose.

I am building a todo list app using classes. (I know this may not be ideal use case of class, but still wanted to get used to utilizing class)

I made a CreateTodoList class with constructor for todoList and todos to store data.

so addTodo basically takes text received from eventHandler to todos(array) and create a DOM element using addtoList(text).

Outside CreateTodoList class, I created another class called 'Events' where its going to handle all the events from the user inputs. all this will do is to call addTodo function passing the user input value.

I tried many ways to get this working, but it seems as though anything inside class can't recognize the variable outside nor I can reference another class methods by using  CreateTodoList.eventListener.

Would you point out whats wrong with the code below, and possibly explain how it works?
Thanks in advance.

```
const add = document.querySelector('#btn_add');
let addInput = document.querySelector('#add');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
class CreateTodoList {
  constructor(list) {
    this.todoList = list;
    this.todos = [];
  }


  addtoList(text) {
    let checkboxEl = document.createElement('span');
    checkboxEl.classList.add('round');
    let checkboxEl2 = document.createElement('input');
    checkboxEl2.id = 'checkbox';
    checkboxEl2.type = 'checkbox';
    let checkboxEl3 = document.createElement('label');
    checkboxEl3.htmlFor = 'checkbox';
    checkboxEl.appendChild(checkboxEl2);
    checkboxEl.appendChild(checkboxEl3);

    let todoTextEl = document.createElement('input');
    todoTextEl.value = text;
    todoTextEl.disabled = true;
    todoTextEl.classList.add('edit_input');
    todoTextEl.id = 'edit_input';
    todoTextEl.type = 'text';
    todoTextEl.name = 'edit_input';
    let todoTextEl2 = document.createElement('label');
    todoTextEl2.htmlFor = 'edit_input';

    let editEl = document.createElement('i');
    editEl.classList.add('far');
    editEl.classList.add('fa-edit');

    let deleteEl = document.createElement('i');
    deleteEl.classList.add('far');
    deleteEl.classList.add('fa-trash-alt');

    let dateEl = document.createElement('small');
    dateEl.textContent = timeago.format(new Date());

    let liEl = document.createElement('li');
    liEl.appendChild(checkboxEl);
    liEl.appendChild(todoTextEl);
    liEl.appendChild(todoTextEl2);
    liEl.appendChild(editEl);
    liEl.appendChild(deleteEl);
    liEl.appendChild(dateEl);

    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.appendChild(li);

    return liEl;
  }

  addTodo(text) {
    this.todos.push(text);
    this.todoList.appendChild(CreateTodoList.addtoList(text));
  }


class Events{
  add.eventHandler('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let userText = document.querySelector('#userInput').value;
  CreateTodoList.addTodo(userText);
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this problem. The first method is instantiating the CreateTodoList class. Classes are data mixed with functions that manipulate that data. Because classes are data, you need to create a variable for their data, otherwise they don't exist as far as the code's concerned. Doing this creates an instance of the class, hence the name instantiation:

```
class Events{
  add_events(){
    add.eventHandler('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let userText = document.querySelector('#userInput').value;

      // Creating an instance
      let todoList = CreateTodoList();
      todoList.addTodo(userText);
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to use classes as a namespace to organize functions, like you're trying to do in your example code, then you need to use the second method, which is using the 'static' keyword.

```
class CreateTodoList{

  // defining addTodo as static
  static function addTodo(text){
    // adding todo list
  }
}
```

This tells the class that you're not trying to manipulate it's data. You can then call the function straight from the class name.

```
class Events{
  add.eventHandler('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let userText = document.querySelector('#userInput').value;

    // calling the static function from the class name
    CreateTodoList.addTodo(userText);
  });
}
```

See more about the static keyword here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static